# JS keylogger not accepting keyup correctly

Tags: javascript, keylogger

I'm pretty new to JS, so I could have made some sort of silly error, but my keylogger doesn't seem to be functioning correctly. It accepts multiple keystrokes correctly, but when one is released, it recognizes both as up. Any help?

Here is my code:

```
var keymap = {};

onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    keymap[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

    if(keymap[39] && keymap[32]){ // Right+Space
        jumpRight();

    }

    if(keymap[37] && keymap[32]){ // Left+Space
        jumpLeft();

    }

    if(keymap[32]){ // Space
        jump();

    }

    if(keymap[39]){ // Right
        right();

    }

    if(keymap[37]){ // Left
        left();

    }
}
```

I'm using Google Chrome, if that helps any.

Thanks!

Comment: That is a strange way to do that? Did you look at other solutions at all before conconcting your own weirdness?

Comment: @adeneo The function looks pretty standard to me, I've used it plenty of times. PS: Don't lowkey insult the few newer people who join and post good questions.

Comment: @Feathercrown - I'm not insulting, but it's strange. Looking at the code, the right thing to do looks like it would be to just bind different functions to the two events, and they using the keyCode directly in comparison. I don't think I've ever seen anyone use an object *(with numeric keys?)* like that to compare keys, even if you claim you've used it plenty of times? I mean, why on earth wouldn't you just do `if (e.which === 39) ...` instead.

Comment: @adeneo Ok, yeah, it should be an array. As for the point of the array, it's so you can use key information outside of the press event, and access keys that are held down during the current press. E.G. `h` is held down, then the player presses `d`, now you can see if `h` is held with this object. It's common in canvas games. For just one-time key reactions, your method is sufficient and preferred because it's less complicated, but it doesn't allow full tracking of the keys.

Comment: @adeneo And as for using individual `if` statements, it becomes way too long. Why use those when you can essentially detect all keys with one line? Basically, the array is used for storage, which is essential to solving this problem (in the question), and many others, such as keeping track of held-down keys, and the non-`if` strategy is shorter and captures all keys to put in the array, allowing easy access by keycode without having to add a line for every key to detect. Using individual variables with their own `if`s for storage would work, but the array is, once again, way easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's recognizing keystrokes correctly, because the array is being updated correctly. The problem is that your functions (`left()`, `right()`, `jump()`, etc.) are only firing when a keypress event happens. When you hold down a key, sometimes it will keep firing keydown events, and sometimes it won't. This causes the functions not to fire, even though your program knows that the key is being held down.

Working example (shows the array values all the time, not just on keypresses; shown array value doesn't necessarily mean the function fires):

```js
var keymap = {};

onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    keymap[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

    if(keymap[39] && keymap[32]){ // Right+Space
        jumpRight();

    }

    if(keymap[37] && keymap[32]){ // Left+Space
        jumpLeft();

    }

    if(keymap[32]){ // Space
        jump();

    }

    if(keymap[39]){ // Right
        right();

    }

    if(keymap[37]){ // Left
        left();

    }
}

document.onkeydown=onkeydown;
document.onkeyup=onkeyup;

function jump(){}
function left(){}
function right(){}
function jumpLeft(){}
function jumpRight(){}

setInterval(function(){console.log(keymap[37]," ",keymap[32]," ",keymap[39]);},5);
```

Nonworking example (how it is right now, shows array values only on keypresses; shown array value == function fires):

```js
var keymap = {};

onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    keymap[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

    if(keymap[39] && keymap[32]){ // Right+Space
        jumpRight();

    }

    if(keymap[37] && keymap[32]){ // Left+Space
        jumpLeft();

    }

    if(keymap[32]){ // Space
        jump();

    }

    if(keymap[39]){ // Right
        right();

    }

    if(keymap[37]){ // Left
        left();

    }
}

document.onkeydown=onkeydown;
document.onkeyup=onkeyup;

function jump(){console.log("jump");}
function left(){console.log("left");}
function right(){console.log("right");}
function jumpLeft(){console.log("jumpleft");}
function jumpRight(){console.log("jumpright");}
```

Note how in the nonworking example, the logging only happens on keydown events, which is when your functions will be called. In the "working" example, the logging happens regardless of key events, but your functions will still fail to fire, since they still happen when key events do. Here's a fully working example:

```js
var keymap = {};

onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    keymap[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
}

document.onkeydown=onkeydown;
document.onkeyup=onkeyup;

function jump(){console.log("jump");}
function left(){console.log("left");}
function right(){console.log("right");}
function jumpLeft(){console.log("jumpleft");}
function jumpRight(){console.log("jumpright");}

function main(){
    if(keymap[39] && keymap[32]){ // Right+Space
        jumpRight();

    }

    if(keymap[37] && keymap[32]){ // Left+Space
        jumpLeft();

    }

    if(keymap[32]){ // Space
        jump();

    }

    if(keymap[39]){ // Right
        right();

    }

    if(keymap[37]){ // Left
        left();

    }
}

setInterval(main,250);
```

Hope this helps!

Good luck learning more JS!

P.S.: You labeled `left()` as "space". :P

Comment: @Jacob Have you clicked "Run code snippet", then also clicked the white area that shows up (the page)?

Comment: @Jacob Also you're welcome. One more thing: `keymap` would be better initialized to `[]` than to `{}`, because you're using numeric keys.

Comment: Whoops.. Works now. Thanks!